# Unhandled Promise Rejection while uploading image to Firebase in react native expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I am getting:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ref._location')`

I even change ref as

```
import { ref as refstore, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
```

So that don't collide with each other. and changes images to blob. I am stuck here not sure what to do next.

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
  const blobimage = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", imageUri, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  })

  const metadata = {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
  };
  // I think something is wrong in the below line **storageRef** <------------
  const storageRef = refstore(storage,`images/${Date.now()}`);
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blobimage, metadata);

  uploadTask.on('state_changed',
    (snapshot) => {
      const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case 'paused':
          console.log('Upload is paused');
          break;
        case 'running':
          console.log('Upload is running');
          break;
      }
    },
   
    
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define **storage** variable with **getStorage** pre-built function.

like this :

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);
```

After initializing Firebase storage, you can pass the storage object to refstore:

```
const storageRef = refstore(storage, `images/${Date.now()}`);
```

Comment: I already imported it from the config file

Comment: my code is working fine on my side. not sure what the exact problem is on your side.

Comment: thanx for pointing out "define storage" There was a silly mistake, forget to use { } at import

Answer (score 0):

Never forget to use {} at import while importing from config file.